# How to get media objects

Tags: php, media, media-library, images, oop

I am busy with a loop to return all media in the medialibrary in objects.
I figured out how to get the images ( with `wp_get_attachment_image('$mediaID')` where the $mediaID is the id of the image )

But I want to loop all media, not just the images, is there a function that I can use for video's and audio that is also from the medialibrary.
I tried `get_attached_media` but this will only work if the media is actually attached and I want to loop all media.

Is there a way to do this and to get it as objects?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

The code I am using is:

```
            <?php
            $query_images_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );

            $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

            foreach ( $query_images->posts as $media) {
                //save the url in a variable to test with
                $media_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $media->ID );

                $mediaID = $media->ID;
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $mediaID );
            }
           ?>
```

P.P.S. I do this because I want to show the media in some sort of library on the front end.
Later there will be categories like 'video', 'audio' and 'img'

Comment: in your code, is `$media` not already an object?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [get_children()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) function?

**Edit:**

All media attached to any post is treated as children of it. The function `wp_get_attachment_image()` will only return images.

With the function `get_children()` you'll be able to get all the media, images or anything else.

In the above link, you can find some examples.

Comment: Arnau, please be a bit more verbose in your answers. Else the community bot will constantly flag your answers as "low quality". For starters, you might want to explain the **why** for your answer :)

Comment: Sorry. I would like to add a simply comment, but i don't have enough reputation. I edited my answer.

Comment: If you got an answer, don't add a comment. Anwers bring upvotes (like now), bring reputation and capabilities. :)